# How can I resize a layer's content now that I have paths in my image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, resize, path, transform

I'm learning how to use Photoshop's pen tool. Now that I have a path in my PSD, I'm having trouble dealing with my unrelated layers. For example, I select a layer on the layer palette, then when I try to resize that layer by hitting CTRL+T, the path gets selected as the thing I want to resize. How do I ignore that path and resize the layer (thereby leaving the path unaffected)? The layer is completely unrelated to the path...

Here's exactly what I did: created a path. After that, I created a new layer and pasted a photo of a horse on that new layer. Now, when I try to resize the photo of the horse (CTRL+T), the path is automatically getting selected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My first thought was that you just needed to select the content in the other layer (CTRL+A or the marquee) and then hit CTRL+T, but that still attempts to resize the path. Anyway, hopefully you'll get better answers here.

Answer (score 2):

Goto the Paths Palette.
Deselect the path by click off it.

Go back to the Layers palette, and select your Layer.
Then transform your layer, the path should not be transformed with it.

Answer (score 0):

The hotkey CTRL+SHIFT+H will toggle the visibility of paths, and will allow you to transform your current layer instead of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the layer panel, often a layer is linked with the masked image, you've to unlink it tu scale independently. 
You could also try with the ( a ) arrow, which select only paths.